# Set up Keycloak 21 with postgres from quay image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I have been trying to set up Keycloak for production without any success.

My Keycloak docker-compose contains:

- SSL
- Postgres

My build does not contains an inverse proxy.

This is my Docker compose:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak_app
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/ssl/keycloak/:/etc/x509/https" # map certificates to container
    environment:
      KC_USER: admin
      KC_PASSWORD: 123
      KC_HOSTNAME: mydomain.net
      KC_DB_VENDOR: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: postgres
      KC_DB: keycloak
      KC_DB_USER: admin
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: 123
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
      KC_DEBUG: true
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: [start]

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This is the one error I am getting. I don't understand what it means and I haven't been able to find anything relative to it:

```
keycloak_app                                   | 
keycloak_app                                   | ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
keycloak_app                                   | ERROR: No value present
keycloak_app                                   | For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
keycloak_app exited with code 1
```

PS: Answers for older version of Keycloak won't work any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **localhost development** following docker-compose file works for me:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest 
    entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start
    container_name: keycloak_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-postgres:5432/keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
    depends_on:
      keycloak-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
  keycloak-postgres:
    container_name: keycloak_postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U keycloak -d keycloak'"] # User, Database
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - keycloak-network

networks:
  keycloak-network:
    name: keycloak-network
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

to adapt this to your needs (configure TLS) it should be probably something like this (not tested):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak_app
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest 
    entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8443:8443
    volumes:
      - "/etc/ssl/keycloak/:/etc/x509/https" # map certificates to container
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
      - KC_HOSTNAME=mydomain.net
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=true
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/etc/x509/https/tls.key
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-postgres:5432/keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      keycloak-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
  keycloak-postgres:
    container_name: keycloak_postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U keycloak -d keycloak'"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - keycloak-network

networks:
  keycloak-network:
    name: keycloak-network
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

## Explanation

Since you have no network defined your keycloak container can't reach your database (besides with using the default docker bridge, which is considered legacy and is not recommended for production use), create a bridge network with

```
networks:
  keycloak-network:
    name: keycloak-network
    driver: bridge
```

then add both container to the network, so they can reach each other with their name or alias

```
networks:
  - keycloak-network
```

now you can use the environment variables like this, note that `keycloak-postgres` is the name of the postgres container

```
KC_DB=postgres # Vendor
KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-postgres:5432/keycloak # Url
KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I have additionally added a healthcheck to the postgres container, because the default healthcheck does not necessarily wait until the database is up and running, this is probably not necessary.

Also binding to a specific address, e.g. `127.0.0.1:8443:8443` is probably a good idea, since `8443:8443` translates to `0.0.0.0:8443:8443`.

Comment: Why do you allow HTTP?

Comment: HTTP is not allowed per default, I did this only for local testing, in the adapted configuration for your use case I did not include `KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true`, so it is not allowed.