# Keycloak Token Endpoint Returning 404 Despite Correct Configuration and URL Format

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using Keycloak 20.1.0 in a Docker container and am encountering a persistent 404 - Not Found error when trying to access the token endpoint via a curl command. My realm is named "hasura-app".

Here is the curl command I'm using:

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://192.168.0.112:8085/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data username=test \
--data password=testtest \
--data grant_type=password \
--data client_id=hasura-app
```

The Keycloak server is running and accessible. I have verified that the realm name and client ID are correct. The user credentials are also correct.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>
```

I have verified the server address, realm name, client ID, client settings, and user credentials. The Keycloak admin console is running and accessible at http://192.168.0.112:8085/auth/admin/.

I've also tried debugging for potential hostname issues, but haven't found a solution yet.

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.6" 
services:
  
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: secret
        KEYCLOAK_USER: blaz
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: secret
      ports:
        - 8085:8080
      depends_on:
        - mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
      driver: local
```

Any help or insights on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

In an attempt to solve the issue, I have tried the following:

Verified Server Address and Port: I confirmed that my Keycloak server is indeed running at the IP address 192.168.0.112 and port 8085.

Checked Realm Name: I made sure that the realm "hasura-app" exists in my Keycloak setup.

Confirmed Client ID: I have verified that the client with the ID "hasura-app" is present within the "hasura-app" realm.

Checked Client Settings: I confirmed that the client "hasura-app" is configured to allow the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type.

Verified User Credentials: I ensured that the user "test" with the password "testtest" is a valid user within the "hasura-app" realm.

URL Format Change: Based on suggestions for Keycloak versions 17 and onwards, I tried removing auth from my request URL. The updated URL was: http://192.168.0.112:8085/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token. However, the 404 error persisted.

Hostname Debugging: I attempted to debug potential hostname issues using a utility tool recommended in the Keycloak community. However, this didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Despite trying all of the above, I'm still facing the 404 error when attempting to access the token endpoint. I would greatly appreciate any further insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

In addition to the aforementioned steps, I also attempted the following:

Uninstalling and Reinstalling Keycloak: I uninstalled Keycloak from my Docker container and then reinstalled it, ensuring that I was using the correct version (20.1). After reinstalling, I set up my realm and client again, but the issue persisted.

Trying Different Configurations: I experimented with different configurations in both the realm and the client settings. This included adjusting the Access Type of the client, enabling and disabling Service Accounts, and modifying the SSL Required setting in the realm. None of these changes resolved the issue.

Recreating the User: I deleted and recreated the user "test" to ensure there was no issue with the user's credentials or settings.

Despite all these efforts, the 404 error when attempting to access the token endpoint continues to occur. Any further help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://192.168.0.112:8085/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Keycloak removed `/auth` when they migrated to Quarkus, you have to prefix it with `/auth` since you use the legacy version.

```
http://192.168.0.112:8085/auth/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

## Addendum

Since switching from wildfly to quarkus is advisable and was asked about in the comment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76396170/20750319) is a link to a non-TLS and TLS setup I already provided for another question.

Comment: I guess, after version 17 /auth is removed. he is already on version 20.

Comment: It was not removed. I ran his docker-compose and it was available at
`http://localhost:8085/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token`. Also he is using the legacy tag, which is using version 19, look [here](https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak?tab=tags).

Comment: Yes. may be right. He mentioned on top that he is using 20.1.0 but in docker compose its legacy which is the latest 19.0.1. Also as the name suggests legacy, it should have '/auth'. The older way of the path should be there.

Comment: @Blaz you can check through. http://192.168.0.112:8085/auth/realms/hasura-app/.well-known/openid-configuration get api first w/ or w/o auth.

Comment: I tried both, with auth and without. When I'm without auth I get 404, but when with auth no matter what data I enter, correct or incorrect, it returns a message

I tried both, with auth and without. When I'm without auth I get 404, but when with auth no matter what data I enter, correct or incorrect, it returns a message: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client secret not provided in request"}

Comment: Probably because you have a confidential client, you need to add the secret to your request. Like this
`curl --request POST \
--url http://192.168.0.112:8085/auth/realms/hasura-app/protocol/openid-connect/token \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data username=test \
--data password=testtest \
--data grant_type=password \
--data client_id=hasura-app \
--data client_secret=<your_secret>`

Comment: @KetanBhavsar what should I do when I open this link. I see huge JSON. What should I look for?

Comment: where I can find that secret. I'm afraid that such an approach will make it difficult for me to connect to my application, if I need a secret in addition to the name and password. How can I turn it off

Comment: You can find that secret when you click on your client and then the `credentials` tab. To turn the confidential client to a public client (so you don't need to provide a secret) you have to turn off `Client authentication`.

However getting the message: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client secret not provided in request"} means you have the correct url for the token endpoint. Do you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: This fix problem. I accidently enable wrong stuff. Thank you very much @DevDan
One of the biggest mistakes is that I accidentally left the legacy version and that made debugging difficult. You really asked me and thank you

Comment: @DevDan I don't get why this answer got downvoted it seems correct to me, unless I am missing something. Maybe you could also suggest as a better approach for OP to move to the Quarkus version instead

Comment: I am running "jboss/keycloak:15.0.2" and this was the problem!